# Swift3, extension to mutablizate a String array

Tags: ios, swift3, extension-methods

I believe you make an extension on a `[String]` like this...

```
extension Sequence where Iterator.Element == String {
```

Say I want to mutate the array - I mean to say, change each of the strings in the array.  How to do?

```
extension Sequence where Iterator.Element == String {
   func yoIzer() {
      for s in self { s = "yo " + s }
   }
}
```

That does not work.

(That's just an example, more complex processing may be required: you may wanna avoid just using a filter.)

Comment: Why an extension? `array = array.map {  "yo " + $0  }`

Comment: That's very true; I became interested in mutation within Extensions.  Also, for that matter I'm unsure if `extension Sequence where Iterator.Element == String` is really the best definition today, for an Extension on `[String]`

Comment: thanks @LeoDabus, that shut me up.  really you should pop it in as an answer to claim the points ... useful for future readers too

Comment: Your code is ridiculous. Changing `s` would not change anything about the array / sequence that `s` comes from. `s` is a copy!

Comment: dude!  ridiculous code is the reason to come here!   :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Sequence is not mutable, and in any case changing the element `s` would not change anything about the Sequence it comes from (`s` is a copy).

What you are trying to say is this:

```
extension MutableCollection where Iterator.Element == String {
    mutating func yo() {
        var i = self.startIndex
        while i != self.endIndex {
            self[i] = "yo" + self[i]
            i = self.index(after: i)
        }
    }
}
```

And here's a test:

```
var arr = ["hey", "ho"]
arr.yo()
print(arr)
// ["yohey", "yoho"]
```

That approach actually comes straight out of the Swift docs.

Comment: However, as has already been pointed out, it seems kind of pointless to do this when `map` already exists.

Comment: "A Sequence is not mutable" facepalm, thanks for that also

Comment: `enumerated().forEach({ self[$0.offset] = "yo " + $0.element })`

Comment: @LeoDabus: That would compile only for collections with `Index == Int`.

Comment: What's the fundamental epistemological reason you can mutate a function in an Extension, but not an ordinary function in a class?

Comment: There are no classes in this story, only structs and protocols, which require the `mutating` keyword if your function will mutate the object.